# vCenter Server Appliance No Healthy Upstream

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vcenter

Recently deployed a vCenter Server appliance to a remote location, it worked fine for the day I was testing and setting it up. The team on the ground redeployed to a second location, keeping all the same network equipment with it.

When they got there and tried to sign in it only shows a "No Healthy Upstream" error. I have made sure that the network configuration matches with the machine that is trying to access it (gateway, DNS, and IP space) as well as instructed them to reboot the appliance and give it more allocated resources (24gb ram & 8 cores CPU) all to no avail.

Anyone have any experience with this or will I likely be stuck with explaining how to redeploy the VCSA over the phone?

Answer (score 0):

this error is common when you have problema with DNS (FQDN). You have to stay sure that A records are created (Reverse too). You can try to deploy vcenter only with IP (don´t complete fqdn field) and see if fqdn is the problem.